# performing action on facebook like button in iphone app

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

```
NSString *likeButtonIframe = @"<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FyoghurtstoryNZ&amp;send=true&amp;width=450&amp;height=480&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true\" scrolling=\"yes\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:visible; width:292px; height:590px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>";
NSString *likeButtonHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><BODY>%@</BODY></HTML>", likeButtonIframe];  
[webView loadHTMLString:likeButtonHtml baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]]; 

-(void)like  {    
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Note" message:@"You are the member of Yoghurt Story." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

This is code I am using to show an alert to display message. But, alert window doesn't appear. Might be action is not getting called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you called the selector. `like` on some event.

Comment: No, but now tried this but not working..                                      NSString *likeButtonIframe = @"<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FyoghurtstoryNZ&amp;send=true&amp;width=450&amp;height=480&amp;action=@selector:(like)&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&amp;header=true\" scrolling=\"yes\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:visible; width:292px; height:590px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>";